# Javascript change

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Help me please,
I have problem to show price list from name product using javascript.
this is code javascript
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkITg.jpg)

```
 $("#detil_type").change(function (){
        $.post("<?PHP echo site_url(); ?>simulasikredit/change_harga", { 
            detil_type: $("#detil_type").val() }, 
            function(response) {
                $("#viewer").html(response);
            }
        );
    });
```

this code for view, I using input for show the price

```
 <div class="form-group" >
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Harga</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div id="viewer">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="harga" id="harga" disabled />
                            </div></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
```

And this **controller**

```
public function change_harga()
    {
        $this->load->model('modelmobil');
        $this->load->model('modelsimulasikredit');
        $harga = $this->input->post('detil_type');
        $data  = $this->modelsimulasikredit->getdataharga($harga);
        $viewer = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="harga" id="harga" value="'.$data.'" disabled />';
        echo $viewer;
    }
```

and **models**

```
public function getdataharga($h="")
{
    $this->db->select("detil_type.harga");
    $this->db->from("detil_type");
    $this->db->where("detil_type.id_detil",$h);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Post your HTML and your controller function as well

Comment: What is the result of your code? What does your endpoint contain?

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari

Comment: @Hienz the code can't show list price after choose type car

Comment: Where is `$("#detil_type")` html element?

Comment: $("#detil_type") get from input type data

Comment: Where is the that input type?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in a php file? If not you can't use php, try this:

```
    $("#detil_type").change(function (){
        $.post("/simulasikredit/change_price", { 
            detil_type: $("#detil_type").val() }, 
            function(response) {
                $("#viewer").html(response);
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ajax` would be better for this purpose

```
$("#detil_type").change(function (){

         $.ajax({
             url: "<?PHP echo site_url(); ?>simulasikredit/change_harga",
             type: "post",
             data: "detil_type="+$('#detil_type').val(),
             dataType: "html",
             success: function(response){
                 $("#viewer").html(response);
             },
             error: function(error){
                 $("#viewer").html(error);
             }
        });        

});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function change_harga()
{
    $this->load->model('modelmobil');
    $this->load->model('modelsimulasikredit');
    $harga = $this->input->post('detil_type');

    //get your query result from your model
    $yourQueryObject  = $this->modelsimulasikredit->getdataharga($harga);

    $data = "";

    //foreach the object item
    foreach($yourQueryObject->result() AS $item)
    {   
        //get the value of item
        $data = $item->harga;
    }

    $viewer = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="harga" id="harga" value="'.$data.'" disabled />';
    echo $viewer;
}
```

**Your model:** I think you do not need `type` table:

```
public function getdataharga($h=""){

        $this->db->select("d.harga");
        $this->db->from("d.harga");
        $this->db->where("d.id_detil",$h);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
}
```

Comment: How about the input? is it appearing?

Comment: yes,,form select car and type car work,but after choose "type mobil" the price didn't show

Comment: I think your query result is empty, please check your query is your table has the row you expected or not

Comment: do you email ?I will send controller,view ,and models from this project

Comment: gm.akbari27@gmail.com

Comment: I think this querry corrent,cause I try sqlyog ,"price data" show

Comment: please check your mailbox,I hope this problem resolved

Comment: What is your main table (detil_type or type) ?

Comment: Why you use table `type`?, cause you are not select any field of it

Comment: 'public function getdataharga($h="")
 {
        $this->db->select("detil_type.harga");
        $this->db->from("detil_type");
        $this->db->where("detil_type.id_detil",$h);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
  }'